# How can I make sbt container:start run tomcat?

Tags: scala, tomcat, sbt

Is there some way to make `container:start` on `sbt 0.12` run `tomcat 7` instead of `jetty`?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to put this on build.sbt: "org.apache.tomcat.embed" % "tomcat-embed-core" % "7.0.40" % "container",
    "org.apache.tomcat.embed" % "tomcat-embed-logging-juli" % "7.0.40" % "container",
    "org.apache.tomcat.embed" % "tomcat-embed-jasper" % "7.0.40" % "container",
    "org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler" % "ecj" % "4.2.2" % "container" , without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/src/tomcat-7/scala/Tomcat7Runner.scala Maybe this? ;-) Please use GitHub search for other variants.

Comment: Nice, I will try to install xsbt-web-plugin.

Comment: It worked! Https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin installed and this includes `"org.apache.tomcat.embed"% "tomcat-embed-core"% "7.0.40"% "container"
     "org.apache.tomcat.embed"% "tomcat-embed-logging-juli"% "7.0.40"% "container"
     "org.apache.tomcat.embed"% "tomcat-embed-jasper"% "7.0.40"% "container"
     "org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler"% "tje"% "4.2.2"% "container"`  in the dependencies.

Comment: also I removed the lines: `"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp"        % "8.1.7.v20120910"  % "container,test",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container,test" artifacts Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar")` from the dependencies

Comment: Link is dead. This is why it's better to copy paste the relevant information and actually *Answer* the question instead of something that would have been better as a comment to OP.